# Need workaround to treat float values as tuples when updating "list" of float values

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, computer-science, floating-point-conversion

I am finding errors with the last line of the for loop where I am trying to update the curve value to a list containing the curve value iterations. I get errors like "can only concatenate tuple (not "float) to tuple" and "tuple object has no attribute 'append'". Does anyone know a way to do this? Thank you...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

thetaR = 0.078
thetaS = 0.43
alpha = 0.0036
psiRange = (range(0,1000))
#psi = 1
#psi = (0,1000)
n = 1.56
curveList = ()
for psi in psiRange:
    curve = (thetaR) + ((thetaS - thetaR)/((1 + (alpha*psi**n))**(1-1/n)))
    #curveList.append(curve)
    curveList += curve

plt.plot(curveList)
plt.axis(0,1,0,100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append to a `tuple` at all (`tuple`s are *immutable*), and extending to a `list` with `+` requires another list.

Make `curveList` a `list` by declaring it with:

```
curveList = []
```

and use:

```
curveList.append(curve)
```

to add an element to the end of it. Or (less good because of the intermediate `list` object created):

```
curveList += [curve]
```

Comment: That easy? How do I make curveList a list though?

Comment: You can use `curveList = []` to initialize an empty `list`: see my edit.